# Sharepoint: How to determine if user is member of group through API

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I need know if some(not only current) user is member of some group.

Moreover, I need know if user placed inside domain group, which placed in sharepoint group.
For example:

Group 'GroupA' contains user 'XXX\Domain Users'. I have user 'XXX\someuser' from domain XXX and need to know if this is member of 'GroupA'. In this example it is true.

For now I found only one way:

Impersonate as specified user and check web.SiteGroups['GroupA'].ContainsCurrentUser

But it is look like hack.

Answer (score 0):

Should be the same as in .NET:

```
principal.IsInRole('GROUPNAME')
```

Or you can try to do following:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
if( principal.IsInRole(@"MYCOMPANY\AllFTE") ){
  // perform operation allowed for fulltime employees
}
```

Maybe that post helps you out: http://mnigbor.blogspot.com/2010/05/using-windowsidentityimpersonate-in.html

Comment: SPUser doesn't have this method(or any like). What is the type of principal ?

Comment: The type would be IPrincipal. Have you seen the Property Groups in the SPUser Class? Maybe this helps you out?

Comment: Property user.Groups contains only sharepoint groups and not contains special groups from windows domain like 'XXX\Domain Users'. :(

Comment: Edited the answer. Have a look.